# No Sound Output - Ubuntu 16.04 (VPS)

Tags: 16.04, server, sound, xfce, vps

So I Deployed my VPS and then Installed ubuntu-desktop, xfce4 & xrdp on my Ubuntu 16.04 (x86_64) using the following cmds.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install xrdp
sudo apt-get install xfce4
echo xfce4-session >~/.xsession
sudo service xrdp restart
```

And then Accessed my Ubuntu Desktop via RDP. But, sadly while trying to run any sound files no sound is coming. I'm a newbie with ubuntu GUI, I just used ubuntu for hosting websites a couple of times, I believe I'm missing something.

Any kind of help will be appreciated.
Have a great day.